# How does lazy evaluation interplay with MVars?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have multiple threads that are reading from a file and I want to make sure that only a single thread is reading from the file at any point in time.

One way to implement this is to use an `mvar :: MVar ()` and ensure mutual exclusion  as follows:

```hs
thread = do
   ...
   _ <- takeMVar mvar
   x <- readFile "somefile"  -- critical section
   putMVar mvar ()
   ...
   -- do something that evaluates x.
```

The above should work fine in strict languages, but unless I'm missing something, I might run into problems with this approach in Haskell. In particular, since `x` is evaluated only *after* the thread exits the critical section, it seems to me that the file will only be read *after* the thread has executed `putMVar`, which defeats the point of using MVars in the first place, as multiple threads may read the file at the same time.

Is the problem that I'm describing real and, if so, how do I get around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's real. You get around it by avoiding all the `base` functions that are implemented using `unsafeInterleaveIO`. I don't have a complete list, but that's at least `readFile`, `getContents`, `hGetContents`. IO actions that don't do lazy IO -- like `hGet` or `hGetLine` -- are fine.

If you must use lazy IO, then fully evaluate its results in an IO action inside the critical section, e.g. by combining `rnf` and `evaluate`.

Some other commentary on related things, but that aren't directly answers to this question:

- Laziness and lazy IO are really separate concepts. They happen to share a name because humans are lazy at naming. *Most* IO actions do not involve lazy IO and do not run into this problem.
- There is a related problem about stuffing unevaluated pure computations into your `MVar` and accidentally evaluating it on a different thread than you were expecting, but if you avoid lazy IO then evaluating on the wrong thread is merely a performance bug rather than an actual semantics bug.

Answer (score 1):

`readFile` should be named `unsafeReadFile` because it's unsafe in the same way as `unsafeInterleaveIO`. If you stay away from functions that have, or should have, the `unsafe` prefix then you won't have this problem.

Haskell isn't a lazily evaluated language. It's language in which, as in mathematics, evaluation order doesn't matter (except that you mustn't spend an unbounded amount of time trying to evaluate a function's argument before evaluating the function body). Compilers are free to reorder computations for efficiency reasons, and GHC does, so programs compiled with GHC aren't lazily evaluated as a rule.

`readFile` (along with `getContents` and `hGetContents`) is one of a small number of standard Haskell functions without the `unsafe` prefix that violate Haskell's value semantics. GHC has to specially disable its optimizations when it encounters such functions because they make program transformations observable that aren't supposed to be observable.

These functions are convenient hacks that can make some toy programs easier to write. You shouldn't use them in threaded code, or, in my opinion, at all. I think they shouldn't even be used in introductory programming courses (which is probably what they were meant for) because they give beginners a totally wrong impression of how evaluation in Haskell is supposed to work.

Comment: ah, *the Haskell Naming Problem* strikes again! --- Haskell programs also mustn't error out when a calculation of an argument errors which isn't yet needed... so it is, in fact, of course, *non-strict* (which is what "lazy" is very often taken to mean).  perhaps you meant "lazy" as in, evaluating strictly by using actual memory-resident memoized thunks.